# How to save SVG image to disk?

Tags: terminal-emacs, images

Looking for a tool to programmatically generate SVG images, I found that
Emacs 26 can do it out of the box!

Example adapted from the [Elisp reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/SVG-Images.html):

```
(require 'svg)
(let ((svg (svg-create 400 400 :stroke-width 10)))
  (svg-gradient svg "gradient1" 'linear '((0 . "red") (100 . "blue")))
  (svg-circle svg 200 200 100 :gradient "gradient1" :stroke-color "green")
  svg)
```

*Now how do I save that to an SVG file?*

I’m using Emacs 26.1 in the [Termux](https://termux.com/) terminal emulator on my phone,
so no graphics.

Comment: `svg` seems to contain XML structure stored as a list. It seems you'd need to just serialize it back to XML, and you'd get a svg string you could save to a file. I'm looking for a function that can do such serialization, and surprisingly, `libxml` has only parsing functions.

Answer (score 3):

Thought I shouldn’t be lazy and found a way by digging around and reading docs. Key is the `svg-print` function which serializes the `svg` structure:

```
(require 'svg)
(let ((svg (svg-create 400 400 :stroke-width 10)))
  (svg-gradient svg "gradient1" 'linear '((0 . "red") (100 . "blue")))
  (svg-circle svg 200 200 100 :gradient "gradient1" :stroke-color "green")
  (with-temp-file "circle.svg"
    (set-buffer-multibyte nil)
    (svg-print svg)))
```

Answer (score 3):

And if, like me, you're trying to do the same in org-mode, `with-temp-buffer` in combination with `buffer-string` does the trick:

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :file test.svg
    (let ((svg (svg-create 400 400 :stroke-width 10)))
      (svg-gradient svg "gradient1" 'linear '((0 . "red") (100 . "blue")))
      (svg-circle svg 200 200 100 :gradient "gradient1" :stroke-color "green")
      (with-temp-buffer
        (svg-print svg)
        (buffer-string)))
#+end_src
```