# SVG in realtime

Tags: images

I'm curious about this presentation in emacs:

[SVG in emacs realtime](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FWQB_9QcGI0)

I could make it working, but refreshing the image manually, following [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/43820/how-to-save-svg-image-to-disk) and using the [svg package](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/svg.html), So I would try to do it in real time using ielm.

[image: working circle]

It seems that the problem is the major-mode image-mode with Imagemagick.  If I use fundamental mode, it works, not well, but it works. In which mode should I open that buffer?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I would like to create that in the ielm, and modify the svg in realtime, seeing the reuslts in emacs buffer

Comment: Follow usage example in the commentary in `svg.el`, use `svg-insert-image`, the picture is updated in realtime.

Comment: I get this error, (svg-insert-image svg)
*** Eval error ***  Text is read-only, also the example in the doc give me an error:
(svg-gradient svg "gradient" 'linear '(0 . "red") '(100 . "blue"))
*** Eval error ***  Wrong number of arguments: (4 . 4), 5

Comment: 1.) For the first error, don't follow that SE question to write the svg data to disk then view it with Emacs. Simply create a fresh buffer and use `svg-insert-image` there. 2). For the second error, you need the newer version 0.1 of svg.el from Gnu Elpa, not the builtin one.

Comment: Regarding my last comment, at least Emacs 26.1 actually provides newer version of svg.el than svg-0.1.el from Gnu Elpa, and it even has documentation [`(info "(elisp) SVG Images")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/SVG-Images.html)

Comment: Finally it worked, I think that we should write a complete answer to this for the sake of completnness

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to the comments of @xuchunyang, it was easy enough to figure and answer to this question just for the sake of completion. the easy way is open ielm (M-x ielm), and split the buufer in Two, then on one ielm do:

```
*** Welcome to IELM ***  Type (describe-mode) for help.
ELISP> (require 'svg)
svg

ELISP> (find-file "test-buffer")
#<buffer test-buffer>
ELISP> ;; create the svg
ELISP> (setf svg (svg-create 400 400))
(svg
 ((width . 400)
  (height . 400)
  (version . "1.1")
  (xmlns . "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")))

ELISP> (svg-insert-image svg)
((width . 400)
 (height . 400)
 (version . "1.1")
 (xmlns . "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
 (:image . #<marker at 1 in test-buffer>))

ELISP> (svg-circle svg 200 200 50)
nil
ELISP> (svg-rectangle svg 100 100 200 200)
nil
ELISP> svg
(svg
 ((width . 400)
  (height . 400)
  (version . "1.1")
  (xmlns . "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
  (:image . #<marker at 1 in test-buffer>))
 (circle
  ((cx . 200)
   (cy . 200)
   (r . 50)))
 (rect
  ((width . 200)
   (height . 200)
   (x . 100)
   (y . 100))))
```

the result is pretty awesome, not this draw, but to see how is easy is to create an svg archive in emacs and view the results

[image: result]

The svg package inuded in emacs is easy to read and to learn for use

ELISP> (info "(elisp) SVG Images")